# Datatable does not works with Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, datatables

I am trying to display data in data in Datatable and  allow the user to download in desired format. But it does not seem to work my data neither gets displayed  nor gets downloaded. This is the code am using at the moment.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {


    var dTable=$('#ex-table').DataTable({
        "bDestroy": true,
        dom: 'lfrtipB',
        buttons: [ 
                    {
                        extend: 'copyHtml5',
                        title: 'Records'
                    },
                    {
                        extend: 'csvHtml5',
                        title: 'Records'
                    },
                    {
                        extend: 'excelHtml5',
                        title: 'Records'
                    },
                    {
                        extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                        title: 'Records'
                    },
                    'print'
                ],
         lengthMenu: [[5, 20, 50, -1], [5, 20, 50, "All"]]

  });


});



var databaseRef = firebase.database().ref("users/");

var table = $('#ex-table').DataTable();

databaseRef.on("child_added", function(data) { 
   var storageObj = data.val();

   var dataSet = [storageObj.Department, storageObj.EmpId, storageObj.Name, storageObj.Position];

   table.rows.add([dataSet]).draw();

});
```

Here is the codepen https://codepen.io/jagrutitiwari/pen/WYBWVy for the code I am trying. Where am I going wrong?

**Update:**

Screenshot of my `users` node:[image]

**Update2**

Security rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

**Update 3**

If I add `dataSrc` to Datatable it works but I cannot see the exports buttons in Datatable now.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {


    var dTable=$('#ex-table').DataTable({
        "bDestroy": true,
        dom: 'lfrtipB',
        data: dataSrc,
        buttons: [ 
              {
                 extend: 'copyHtml5',
                 title: 'Records'
               },
               {
                 extend: 'csvHtml5',
                 title: 'Records'
               },
               {
                  extend: 'excelHtml5',
                  title: 'Records'
               },
               {
                   extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                   title: 'Records'
               },
                   'print'
               ],
         lengthMenu: [[5, 20, 50, -1], [5, 20, 50, "All"]]

  });


});
```

Comment: Trying your codepen I have the feeling your database is empty (for the `users` node)

Comment: I have updated my question with the screenshot of data. Could you please check it again?

Comment: Can you also share your security rules. Because apparently users need to be authenticated in order to read the data, see the message at the top of the screen you shared.

Comment: Updated question with security rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your security rules, your users need to be authenticated in order to read (and write to) the database.

With the code you show in your question (an excerpt of your entire HTML page, I guess), it seems that you don't ask the users to authenticate, therefore you don't get any record when you query the database.

You should either integrate an authentication mechanism, for example using FirebaseUI Auth (see https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web), or, if your database is in test, give a try with "public" rules, like:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Renaud. The code does works now. But why is it that Datatable's search bar is not working? Am not able to download the Firebase data using datatable as well. Do you have any idea what could the reason be?

Comment: This is probably due to the fact that when you load your DataTable there is no data, since the `on()` listener is asynchronous. In other words, you use the JavaScript mode (https://datatables.net/manual/data/#Javascript) but with an empty data set. You should look the possibilities of the Ajax sourced data (https://datatables.net/manual/data/#Ajax) and possibly use the Firebase REST API. But this should probably be treated in a totally new SO question.

Comment: Hi Renaud, could you please see the third update in the question? I think I have got it figured partially. The Datatable now atleast recognizes the data, also the search feature works but the export buttons disappear.